# Need to apply a function only on one div

Tags: javascript, html

The function newCards() selects three cards from a deck and places them inside three divs.

I want a fuction that then randomly selects one of the three divs and applies newCards() on the randomly selected div and changes the card.

I already have a 'random' variable which is a randomly selected div, but I don't know how to properly apply the function only on that 'random' variable.

```
function changeCard () {
var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * $('.cards').length);}

function newCards() {
createDeck();
document.querySelector("#img-1").classList.remove('invert');
document.querySelector("#img-2").classList.remove('invert');
document.querySelector("#img-3").classList.remove('invert');
var percentRevs = 50;

for (var b = 1; b <= 3; b++) {
    //$("#rev-" + b).html("");
    var rand = randGen();
    var randInvert = Math.floor((Math.random() * 101));
    
    if (randInvert >= percentRevs) {
        $("#img-" + b).html(riderWaite(rand));       
        $("#info-UP-" + b).html("<p>").removeClass("invisible");
        $("#info-UP-" + b).append(meanings.upright[rand - 1].name);
        $("#info-RE-" + b).html("<p>").addClass("invisible");
        $("#info-RE-" + b).append(meanings.reversed[rand - 1].name);
    } else {
        $("#img-" + b).html(riderWaite(rand)).addClass("invert");
        $("#info-RE-" + b).html("<p>").removeClass("invisible");
        $("#info-RE-" + b).append(meanings.reversed[rand - 1].name);
        $("#info-UP-" + b).html("<p>").addClass("invisible");
        $("#info-UP-" + b).append(meanings.upright[rand - 1].name);
    }
}
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I would try having the changeCard function take an argument to know which card element to change. If you know there are only three card divs, then you can pretty safely have each one call the function specifically with their appropriate class or index.

Then just change that one card in a manner similar to what you do in your other function

Comment: Hey I came up with a pretty primitive solution but not sure why it doesn't work. I thought I'd just create three functions for each div and then create different cases inside the changeCard function and if the random div matches one of the divs i'd just call the function for it. 

var card1 = document.getElementById('img-1')

function changeCard() {
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * $('.cards').length);

    switch (random){
        case card1:
         newCards1()
         break;
    }
}